# Dynamically adding <br>

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically add a `<br>` element after a dynamically added `<div>`. Even though the `<br>` is added in the code (I saw it under Elements in Chrome), the line doesnt appear on the screen. This is my code:

```
let guests = document.createDocumentFragment();
let k = 0;
let name = [];
for(let j = 0; j < compositions[i].guests.length; j++){
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  let divElement = document.createElement("div");

  if(compositions[i].guests[k] != ";"){
    name.push(compositions[i].guests[k]);
    k++;
}
  else {
    k = k + 2;
    divElement.innerHTML = name.join('');
    divElement.setAttribute("class", "guestsDiv");
    divElement.setAttribute("id", "guestsDiv");
    divElement.setAttribute("style", "color:" + compositions[i].textColor);
    guests.appendChild(br);
    guests.appendChild(divElement);
    //$('#guests').append('New Line<br>');
    name = [];
  }
}
```

This is the css:

```
.guestsDiv{
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
   top: 16.5vw;
   left: 59.5vw;
   max-width: 2px;
   font-size: 2vw;
   line-height: 98%;
   word-wrap: normal;
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 }
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/config.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/config.js" defer></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="backgroundImage" name="lname" placeholder="Background Image">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="animation" name="lname" placeholder="Animation">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="textColor" name="lname" placeholder="Text Color">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="overlay" name="lname" placeholder="Overlay">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="startDate" name="lname" placeholder="Start Date">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="config" id="endDate" name="lname" placeholder="End Date">
  <br>
  <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Enter values" onclick="configComp();"/>

  <img id="setBackground">
  <img id="logo">
  <div id="rectangle"></div>
  <div id="smallRectangle"></div>
  <div id="welcomeFirstLine" style="position:absolute"></div>
  <div id="welcomeSecondLine" style="position:absolute"></div>
  <div id="emptyText" style="position:absolute"></div>
</body>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.5.0/velocity.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2/velocity.ui.min.js'></script>

</html>
```

It has to be something easy, but I cant see what. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

P.S.: If you also have some other suggestions about my code I'm open to it. So please feel free to give me any feedback.

**Edit:** For clarification: all elements are shown, but one on top of eachother and not one under eachother as I want.

**Edit2:** More code added.

Comment: you should post your html and css too, by the way I suggest to use the inspect tool with chrome and check your div element size and heigth and see if the br is hide by this

Comment: May be you need to use `<hr>`?

Comment: Are you referring to a visual line or extra vertical spacing? A [MCVE] would be helpful

Comment: So I am dynamically adding some lines of text as `div`, but they overlap when shown on the screen and I want to show them one under each other.

Comment: attach a screenshot that shows how it's displaying or create a codepen or jsfiddle or something. would be kind of difficult to troubleshoot this without that

Comment: is the `position: absolute` rule ever overwritten? (I hope at least the `display:none` is) Otherwise, since they are absolutely positioned, with a fixed top and left, yes, they'll overlap, whatever is in the DOM.

Comment: @Kaiido you were right, they were overlpping because of the `position: absolute`, but now I dont know to make the elements move- the css doenst seem to have any influence

Comment: @Kaiido it works with `padding-left`, but could you explain to me why? I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an issue with the creation of br element. The thing is you are using the same br element each time in the loop, which means each time the dom paints it at different positions throughout the loop (which here is before the new div).

So you can either clone the br element or create a new one each time like :

```
let guests = document.createDocumentFragment();
let k = 0;
let name = [];
var br = document.createElement("br"); //<-- Outside, to avoid redeclaration.
for(let j = 0; j < compositions[i].guests.length; j++){

  let divElement = document.createElement("div");

  if(compositions[i].guests[k] != ";"){
    name.push(compositions[i].guests[k]);
    k++;
}
  else {
    k = k + 2;
    divElement.innerHTML = name.join('');
    divElement.setAttribute("class", "guestsDiv");
    divElement.setAttribute("id", "guestsDiv");
    divElement.setAttribute("style", "color:" + compositions[i].textColor);
    guests.appendChild(br.cloneNode()); // <-- Here cloneNode() creates a new clone of br each time.
    guests.appendChild(divElement);
    //$('#guests').append('New Line<br>');
    name = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are still overlapping

Comment: Is that the final CSS ? I mean after creating the guests fragment are you modifying any of the style properties of guests Div?

Comment: Yes, that is the final CSS. I solved the problem with removing the `position: absolute` and then using `padding-left`, even though Im not sure why it doesnt also work just with `left`.

Comment: What do I do know that I found a solution from the comments and not from the answers? How do I "close" the question?